# Read Data from JSON link

Tags: angular8

So I have a JSON file I am reading my web content from
It looks something like:

```
{
  "id": 2213423,
    "name": "Barak Obama",
      "title": "Former US President",
        "education": "Havard",
          "picUrl": "assets/img/obama.jpg",
            "bioUrl": "assets/presidents/obama.txt"
}
```

Here is my Goal:
When the page is rendered, I would like To retrieve all this information, however for the bioUrl, I would like to read it from another file, since the text in it can be rather lengthy

I created a service using that returns me all the information appropriately,
  I have bound the pic Url to the source Tag:

However, I cannot accomplish the same thing for the bioUrl
Is there anyway to go about this ?
 biography.component.ts
profileBio: IProfileInfo;
    enter code here

```
enter code here

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private aboutService: AboutService) {
      console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
}
enter code here

ngOnInit() {
    const paramId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (paramId) {
    const id = +paramId;
    this.getProfile(id);
  }



 getProfile(id: number) {
    this.aboutService.getAProfile(id).subscribe(
        profile => this.profileBio = profile,
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-angle-bracket-type-assertion
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
```

biography.component.html

```
enter code here



 img class="image"[src] = 'profileBio?.picUrl' alt = "Services"

    < mat - card - content >
    <h1>{{ profileBio ?.name}
} </h1>
  < h3 > {{ profileBio ?.education}}</h3>
    < h4 > {{ profileBio ?.title}}</h4> 
      < /mat-card-content>

      < div class="content" >
        <p>Struggle...How to retrieve the file content from this file ? </p>    

   { { profileBio ?.bioUrl} } // this returns me assets/presidents/obama.txt     
</div>
```

about - service.service.ts

```
 private profilesUrl = 'assets/api/v1/profiles/profiles.json';

getAProfile(id: number): Observable < IProfileInfo | undefined > {
  return this.getProfiles().pipe(
    map((profile: IProfileInfo[]) => profile.find(p => p.id === id))
  );
}

getProfiles(): Observable < IProfileInfo[] > {
  return this.http.get<IProfileInfo[]>(this.profilesUrl).pipe(
    tap(
      eldersList => console.log('')),
    //  eldersList => console.log('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(eldersList))),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

It is returning me the link: assets / presidents / obama.txt
Instead of the content of the link...

Is there anyway I can retrieve the content of the link like in the case of img[src] =.../?

Answer (score 0):

your json need to look like

```
     {
      "profile0": {
         "id": 2213423,
         "name": "Barak Obama",
         "title": "Former US President",
         "education": "Havard",
         "picUrl": "assets/img/obama.jpg",
         "bioUrl": "assets/presidents/obama.txt"
      },
      "profile1" : {
          ... 
      }
    }
```

Then, in your service, need to read every line:

```
let list: IProfileInfo[] = [];
getProfiles(): Observable < IProfileInfo[] > {
  return this.http.get<IProfileInfo[]>(this.profilesUrl).pipe(
    map(
      (eldersList: IProfileInfo[]) => {
         for (let i = 0; i <= eldersList.length; i++) {
            list.push(eldersList['profile' + i]);
          }
      return list;
})
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,
My JSON does look like that, I only provided 1 profile, sorry about that...

I can also read the file from the service, everything is checking out correctly...
The only problem I have, is that I cannot retrieve the content from the bioUrl... instead of returning me what I have in the obama.txt, it is returning me the link, i.e assests/presidents/obama.txt